# Document has textTabs but they don't get returned with the document as a pdf

Tags: docusignapi

I'm creating an envelope with a single document successfully with the api.  I'm passing over some info to the document with textTabs, this is working fine and I think this is the correct way to do a mailmerge as far as I can tell.

However, now I'm trying to retrieve the document back as a PDF, I get it back, but it doesn't have the textTabs.  Why does this happen?

Edit: Here's my envelope create, i've snipped a few of the tabs out.

```html
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <status>sent</status>
  <emailSubject>DocuSign API - Embedded Signing example</emailSubject>
  <enableWetSign>false</enableWetSign>
  <templateId>a5413dda-74a6-40a1-b9c5-de5634ba32ab</templateId>
  <templateRoles>
    <templateRole>
      <email>email@email.com</email>
      <name>Fred Bloggs</name>
      <roleName>Customer</roleName>
      <clientUserId>1</clientUserId>
      <tabs>
        <textTabs>
          <text>
            <anchorString>[DealerName]</anchorString>
            <tabLabel>label</tabLabel>
            <value>Fred Bloggs Dealer</value><font>Arial</font>
            <fontSize>Size10</fontSize>
            <bold>true</bold>
            <locked>true</locked>
            <documentId>1</documentId>
            <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
          </text>
          <text>
            <anchorString>[DealerABN]</anchorString>
            <tabLabel>label</tabLabel>
            <value>12345678901</value><font>Arial</font>
            <fontSize>Size10</fontSize>
            <bold>true</bold>
            <locked>true</locked>
            <documentId>1</documentId>
            <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
          </text>
        </textTabs>
      </tabs>
    </templateRole>
  </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

This works fine and I can see the tabs filled out in the document on docusign.

Then I retrieve the document uri and get it as a PDF with the following code, taken from the API walkthrough:

```
Dim url As String = BaseURL + "/envelopes/" + EnvelopeID + "/documents"

Dim request As HttpWebRequest = initializeRequest(url, "GET", Nothing, DocuSignUserName, DocuSignPassword, DocuSignIntegratorKey)

Dim response As String = GetResponseBody(request)

Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(response)
Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.docusign.com/restapi")

Dim DocumentUri As String = Nothing
For Each DocumentNode As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("x:envelopeDocumentsResult/x:envelopeDocuments/x:envelopeDocument", nsmgr)
    Dim IdNode As XmlNode = DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("x:documentId", nsmgr)
    If (IdNode IsNot Nothing) Then
        If (String.Compare(IdNode.InnerText, DocumentId, True) = 0) Then
            Dim UriNode As XmlNode = DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("x:uri", nsmgr)
            If (UriNode IsNot Nothing) Then
                DocumentUri = UriNode.InnerText()
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

If (DocumentUri = Nothing) Then
    Throw New Exception("DocumentId '" + DocumentId + "' not found")
End If

url = BaseURL + DocumentUri
request = initializeRequest(url, "GET", Nothing, DocuSignUserName, DocuSignPassword, DocuSignIntegratorKey)
request.Accept = "application/pdf"
```

But the PDF only has the template info, the tabs are missing

Comment: Are you saying the tabs themselves are not filled out on the document, or the data within them is not being returned in your API call?

A sample of your envelope create as well as retrieval call would help, make sure you remove the login details from your header (if included).

Comment: Hi Rickey, yes, the tabs are not filled out in the PDF document when I get it back.  They are filled out on the docusign site when I go there for signing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs are always specific to recipients, meaning tabs can only be assigned to recipients and do not "belong" to the document per say.  If you want to retrieve the tab info try making the [Get Tab Information for Recipient](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Tab%20Information%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm) API call.

Sample Request from the docs:

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "textTabs":[{
    <Tab information removed>
  }],
  "titleTabs":[{
    <Tab information removed>
  }],
  "signHereTabs":[{
    <Tab information removed>
 }]
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need the tab info though, I need a fully rendered PDF of the document including tabs.  Is it not possible?  Or is there another way I should be putting data into a document?

Comment: You should be able to do that.  What status is the envelope in when you download the doc, are you sure it's completed?

Comment: Yes!  That's it, I hadn't completed it.  Tried now and worked as expected.  Thanks for that!!!